# Filtering with case by case criteria in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a dataframe like this:

```
| ID | VisitNum | Type        |
|----|----------|-------------|
| 1  | 1        | Store       |
| 1  | 1        | Online      |
| 2  | 3        | Catalog     |
| 2  | 3        | SmokeSignal |
| 3  | 100      | Walk-In     |
```

I want to remove duplicate rows, but there is a pesky set of human-defined criteria for what to remove. Basically,

"If ID and VisitNum show up more than once, then
 If the duplicate values for Type are Store and Online, remove the row with Online
OR
If the duplicate values for Type are Catalog and SmokeSignal, remove the row with SmokeSignal"

The output would be:

```
| ID | VisitNum | Type        |
|----|----------|-------------|
| 1  | 1        | Store       |
| 2  | 3        | Catalog     |
| 3  | 100      | Walk-In     |
```

I wanted to use dplyr and do some grouping and filtering...I'm thinking something like this:

```
 dupes <- dupes %>%
  group_by(ID, VisitNum) %>%
  summarise(Count=n() )
  filter( <here's where I get stuck...some condition where the Count is greater than 1 then...> )
```

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

And here is my dataframe:

```
dupes <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3), VisitNum=c(1, 1, 3, 3, 100), Type=c('Store', 'Online', 'Catalog', 'SmokeSignal', 'Walk-In'))
```

Comment: would you always want to fill with the first Type occuurance by group? or is there some sort of logic for which Type variant to keep? other than your conditional statements, of course

Comment: The only logic is just the rules in the post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example, we can use `slice` to get the first element assuming that the 'Type' is already in order

```
library(dplyr)
dupes %>%
   group_by(ID, VisitNum) %>%
   slice(1)
#   ID VisitNum    Type
#  <dbl>    <dbl>  <fctr>
#1     1        1   Store
#2     2        3 Catalog
#3     3      100 Walk-In
```

---

Or based on the criteria

```
dupes %>% 
     group_by(ID, VisitNum) %>% 
     filter((n() > 1 & !(Type %in% c("Online", "SmokeSignal")))| n()==1)
#     ID VisitNum    Type
#  <dbl>    <dbl>  <fctr>
#1     1        1   Store
#2     2        3 Catalog
#3     3      100 Walk-In
```